# ClassCastException in oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

I am getting a `ClassCastException` while creating a `ArrayDescriptor` in web application.
I am getting the connection from Tomcat DBCP Connection pool  using jndi lookup.
I am using ojdbc.jar  14 driver jar, Oracle 11g server, Tomcat 7 server and JDK 8.
I am not getting the oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection object from the connection that is returned from the pool.

Below is the error stack trace :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
        at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:149)
        at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:115)
```

the connection sysout is:

```
ProxyConnection[PooledConnection[oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@770799c2]]
```

JNDI config in server.xml in Tomcat below:-

```
 Resource
         name="jdbc/my_db"
         auth="Container"``
         type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
         initialSize="5"
         maxActive="5"
         maxIdle="2"
         minIdle="1"
         maxTotal="10"
         maxWaitMillis="10000"
         timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000"
         minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000"
         validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
         validationInterval="34000"
         testOnBorrow="true"
         removeAbandoned="true"
         removeAbandonedTimeout="55"
         driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
         url="jdbc:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         username="aaaaaaa"
         password="bbbbbbbbbb"
         connectionProperties="SetBigStringTryClob=true"
         accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"/>
```

using Hibernate to get connection:-

```
getSession().doWork(new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

                ArrayDescriptor descNum = 
     ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("ARRAY_NUMC", connection );
}
```

I also used connection unwrap method , but not works.

Comment: "I also used connection unwrap method , but not works." Which result and connection get you ?

Comment: got error during unwrap(OracleConnection.class):-                   
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Not a wrapper of oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.unwrap(ProxyConnection.java:87)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:119)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.unwrap(Unknown Source)

Comment: Should work for you too. Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58233348/8413677

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use the latest JDBC driver i.e., [12.2.0.1 JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html) is available on OTN.