# Cannot cast from ConnectionWrapper to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection using JAVA1.8 and Tomcat 8.5.28

Tags: java, tomcat8

Why connection is not working after few seconds? Application is hanging up and not running as expected and returning the below error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
>   cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection

Below is the code that is used to get the connection:

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) 
((DelegatingConnection)connection).getInnermostDelegate();
```

using libraries: commons-pool1.6.jar for encryption & tomcat-dbcp.jar for database.

Using encrypted username and password in Tomcat context.xml.

Also, using accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true in context.xml file.

Issue is with JAVA8 and Tomcat8. Able to work properly with plain credentials, the only issue happens with encrypted credentials.

Comment: Shouldnt you be using `connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);` instead of what you have now? You are on Tomcat8 and I assume you are on a recent java version providing JDBC 4.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Tried this unwrap also and didn't work.We are using JAVA1.8, Tomcat 8.5.28 and ojdbc7.jar.

Comment: @MaheshReddy did you find a solution? I am facing same issue. It is not able to get a connection after n no. of hits.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do casting or unwrapping. Use correct DataSource type in Tomcat 'conf/context.xml' file. In case of Oracle it is: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.
Set also correct driver and factory.
Look at this example of mine:

```
<Context>

<!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
<!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->
<Resource name="UNCUNC"
          auth="Container"
          type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
          factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"

          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@p260unc4.big.ru:1566:uncunc"
          user="dsserv"
          password="dsservPass" 

          connectionProperties="SetBigStringTryClob=true"
          maxTotal="20" maxIdle="10"
          maxWaitMillis="-1"/>              
<JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
```

Later in the java code use it like this (don't cast):

```
try {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("UNCUNC");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.error("DATASOURCE error", e);
    }
 Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Should work just fine. Take attention in different versions of Tomcat you need to use 'username' instead 'user' field.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. After a lot of analysis realized it was classloading issue. Fixed the issue by providing ojdbc jar in shared.loaded (in conf/catalina.properties)

```
shared.loader="/path/to/ojdbcN_jar/ojdbcN.jar"
```

This will make sure that the OracleConnection classes are loaded from the same jar in Tomcat and in the deployed webapp.

And in the application where OracleConnection is needed, use the below:

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

Note: In my application I have ojdbc jar so that my application compiles fine, but when deployed, the jar used will be the one mentioned in shared loader.

Also don't forget to enable accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed when creating the Tomcat JDBC connection pool